# C++ Boost using newton_raphson_iterate on a class member function

Tags: c++, boost

My code below doesn't compile and can't get it why. Is it because I'm using the `newton_raphson_iterate` in a wrong way?

Do I need to use binding ? Any examples of how using the newton raphson on a member class function is welcome.

```
class MyB{

    struct funct{
        double target;
        double DerivativePrecision;
        int mo;
        bool isG;
        MyB* bond;
    public:
        funct(double target_, double DerivativePrecision_, int mo_, bool isG_, MyB* bond_ ) : 
          target(target_), DerivativePrecision(DerivativePrecision_), mo(mo_), isG(isG_), bond(bond_)
        {}
        std::tr1::tuple<double,double> operator()(const double& x) const {
          double localYtP = bond->yTp(x, mo, isG);
          return std::tr1::make_tuple ( 
              localYtP - target, 
              (bond->yTp(x+DerivativePrecision,mo, isG)-localYtP)/DerivativePrecision
              );
        }
    };      

    public:
        /*
        .....           
        */
        double yTp(double x, int mo, int  isG);

        double pty(double p, int mo, int isG){
            funct localFunc(p, 0.000001, mo, isG, this);
            double y = boost::math::tools::newton_raphson_iterate(localFunc(p),
                                                                    0.1, 
                                                                    -0.1, 
                                                                    0.4,
                                                                    std::numeric_limits<double>::digits
                                                                    );
            return y;
        }           
}   

int main()
{   
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I get two error messages :

First :

```
\boost/math/tools/roots.hpp(202) : error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

pointing to the last line of this code (BOOST):

```
template <class F, class T>
T newton_raphson_iterate(F f, T guess, T min, T max, int digits, boost::uintmax_t& max_iter)
{
   BOOST_MATH_STD_USING

   T f0(0), f1, last_f0(0);
   T result = guess;

   T factor = static_cast<T>(ldexp(1.0, 1 - digits));
   T delta = 1;
   T delta1 = tools::max_value<T>();
   T delta2 = tools::max_value<T>();

   boost::uintmax_t count(max_iter);

   do{
      last_f0 = f0;
      delta2 = delta1;
      delta1 = delta;
      boost::math::tie(f0, f1) = f(result);
...
```

The second :

```
see reference to function template instantiation 'T boost::math::tools::newton_raphson_iterate<std::tr1::tuple<_Arg0,_Arg1>,double>(F,T,T,T,int)' being compiled
```

pointing (in my class ) to

```
double y = boost::math::tools::newton_raphson_iterate(localFunc(p),
                                                                    0.1, 
                                                                    -0.1, 
                                                                    0.4,
                                                                    std::numeric_limits<double>::digits
                                                                    );
```

Comment: *"My code below doesn't compile"*: what does the compiler say? What are the error(s) and in which line(s)?

Comment: You shouldn't pass as argument to `newton_raphson_iterate` `localFunc(p)` which is a call to operator() of your functor, but `localFunc` which is effectively your functor. And `newton_raphson_iterate` needs 6 arguments: you're missing one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're calling `localFunc` when trying to invoke `newton_raphson_iterate` so end up passing a `funct` as the first template parameter, which is not callable. You should just pass `localFunc` directly:

```
newton_raphson_iterate(localFunc, 0.1, -0.1, 0.4, std::numeric_limits<double>::digits);
```